# Verificar sequencia ordenada (em ordem crescente ou decrescente)

Tags: java

Uma sequência de números inteiros, verifique se está ordenada `true` (em ordem crescente ou decrescente), caso contrário, é `false`. Se um número tiver o mesmo valor que o número abaixo, ele não quebrará a ordem. A sequência termina com `0`.

```
Sample Input 1: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
Sample Output 1:true
--------------------------------
Sample Input 2: 1 2 3 3 9 0
Sample Output 2:true
--------------------------------
Sample Input 3: 1 2 5 5 2 3 0
Sample Output 3: false
--------------------------------
```

Preciso de ajuda, estou tentando há dias ... Realmente aprecio qualquer ajuda ...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 0;
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            int i = s.nextInt();
            a = i;
            if (i < a) {
                if (i < a) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                } else if (i > a) {
                    System.out.println("false");
                    break;
                }
            } else if (i > a) {
                if (i > a) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                } else if (i < a) {
                    System.out.println("false");
                    break;
                }
            } else if (i == a) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conforme a ajuda que recebi do *Arvind Kumar Avinash*, segue a explicação da solução que aprendi com a resposta :D**

1. Com base nas duas primeiras entradas (precisa de uma variável de contador, por exemplo count), decida se os números restantes devem estar em ordem crescente ou decrescente. Pode usar uma variável `boolean`, por exemplo, `asc` para armazenar este resultado, ou seja, se o segundo número for maior que o primeiro, o valor de `asc` será true; caso contrário false,
2. Depois de decidir o valor dos `asc` dois primeiros números, é necessário verificar se o próximo número segue esse padrão ou não. Se o próximo número não seguir o padrão, imprima false e interrompa o processamento.
3. Para cada número que o scanner lê, você também precisa verificar se é `0`. Se sim, imprima true e interrompa o processamento. Além disso, como o requisito menciona, *"Se um número tiver o mesmo valor que o número abaixo, ele não quebrará a ordem"*, simplesmente continue quando o número lido pelo scanner tiver o mesmo valor que o último número lido.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean asc = true;
        int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (count < 2) {
                i = s.nextInt();
                if (i == 0) {
                    System.out.println(true);
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            } else {
                // Store the last input to `i` and read a new number into `j`
                i = j;
                j = s.nextInt();

                // Continue if the new number has the same value as the last read number
                if (i == j) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.println(true);
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
            if (count <= 2) {
                j = s.nextInt();

                // Continue if the new number has the same value as the last read number
                if (i == j) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.println(true);
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }

            // Based on the first two inputs decide whether the remaining numbers should be
            // in ascending order or in descending order.
            if (count == 2 && j < i) {
                asc = false;
            }

            // Check if the next number (i.e. the value of `j`) follows this pattern or not
            if ((asc == true && j < i) || (asc == false && j > i)) {
                System.out.println(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

A sample run:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
true
```

Another sample run:

```
1 2 3 3 9 0
true
```

Another sample run:

```
1 2 5 5 2 3 0
false
```

Another sample run:

```
9 9 8 0
true
```

Another sample run:

```
5 5 6 0
true
```